# How to compare two URLs in JavaScript Postman Runner

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

I want to compare two URLs: the first from the response and the second from the uploaded CSV file.

I want to check that the URL in the response is the same URL linked to the requested row in the CSV file.

**The request body**

```
{
"brandTrigram": "{{brandTrigram}}",
"countryId": "{{countryId}}",
"languageId": "{{languageId}}"
}
```

**Tests**

```
pm.test("Check returned data", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.URL).to.eql(pm.variables.get("URL"));
});
```

The CSV file

```
brandTrigram,countryId,languageId,URL
car,ca,eng,https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/others/privacy-policy.html
car,ae,ara,https://www.cartier.ae/ar-ae/%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%B0%D9%84%D9%83/%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A9.html
```

I get the following error for the first iteration in the CSV file:

```
Check returned data | JSONError: Unexpected token 'h' at 1:1 https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/others/privacy-policy.html ^
```

**So the javascript test is not doing the job of comparison we want :/ , how can i solve that ?**

[image: DATA PREVIEW]

Comment: What does the response body look like?

Comment: @DannyDainton actually in the response body there is the expected URL (e.g https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/others/privacy-policy.html)

Comment: What's the structure though? Is it just a single key `URL` in an object. Trying to understand what `jsonData.URL` represents. Without all the details, how can people help you.

Comment: @DannyDainton `jsonData.URL` is the expected response, we provide 3 values and we should get in the response an URL, what I want from my JS test is to make sure that this URL is the same URL linked to the values in the request according to the CSV file.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, why is it so difficult to update the question with an example of the response body? You have a request body there, just do the same as the response. Is it `{ "URL": "https://example.com" }` and that's it or is it some other structure?

Comment: @DannyDainton for this request for e.g`{"brandTrigram": "car","countryId": "ca","languageId": "eng"}` i get as a response body `https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/others/privacy-policy.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your response body is:

```
{
    "URL": "some URL"
}
```

The test could be:

```
pm.test("Check returned data", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.URL).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("URL"));
});
```

Using `pm.iterationData.get()` ensures you're getting the value from that scope and avoids issues if you have that variable name in a different scope.

I don't know what the response body structure is so this is a guess based on seeing `jsonData.URL` in the question.

**EDIT**

It looks like the response is plain text and not a JSON object so using either `pm.response.json()` or `jsonData.URL` is incorrect.

```
pm.test("Check returned data", function () {
    var response = pm.response.text();
    pm.expect(response).to.include(pm.iterationData.get("URL"));
});
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest but still, get the same error for the test "Check returned data" :/

Comment: So the response body is just a plain text string?

Comment: This is the reason why I asked for the response body, it's a big deal when trying the reference something....in the response. :D You're trying to parse a string as JSON with `pm.response.json()` and then trying to reference something that doesn't exist by using `jsonData.URL`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: now i get a different error but better :D `Check returned data | AssertionError: expected 'https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/others/privacy-policy.html' to include undefined`

Comment: Does each iteration in the data file have the URL value? What does the preview of the data file look like in the collection Runner?

Comment: Please find the data preview in the post above

Comment: You can see on that image that the URL column isn't right